# Can't remove or stop AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that I load onto a new view whenever a link is clicked.

```
-(void)createAndConfigurePlayerWithURL:(NSURL *)movieURL sourceType:(MPMovieSourceType)sourceType {
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL];
customControlOverlay = [[AFDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AFMovieScrubControl" bundle:nil];
backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[customControlOverlay.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:customControlOverlay.view];

playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
[playerLayer.player play];
playerLayer.frame = customControlOverlay.view.frame;
[customControlOverlay.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer]; 
}
```

The code above adds the AVPlayer to my app and works fine. I have a toggle in my customControlOverlay nib that should remove the view and stop the AVplayer from playing.

```
-(IBAction)toggleQuality:(id)sender {
if (qualityToggle.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"HD");
    [playerLayer.player pause];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

} else if (qualityToggle.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    NSLog(@"SD");
}
}
```

The view is removed correctly but the player still plays in the background.  After testing a bit the player wont respond to any code in the toggleQuality method but strings I have there as checks are getting logged.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use playerLayer.player = nil; before you remove from superview

Comment: The sound keeps playing even if I do that.

Comment: What if you do that in the other order (remove and then set to nil)?

Comment: Tried changing the order and it still doesn't remove.

Comment: Check that playerLayer isn't nil, for some reason.

Comment: **Use playerLayer.player = nil; before you remove from superview** should be the right answer. Below answer didn't work for me.

Comment: A similar problem happens with `AVSynchronizedLayer`. In that case, you need to release the `playerItem`, e.g.:  `yourSyncLayer.playerItem = nil` or `yourSyncLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()`.

Answer (score 27):

*I know it's an old question, but it might be helpful to someone someday.*

Since the **playerLayer** is being added as a `sublayer` and not as a `subview` it simply needs to be removed from its superlayer (instead of the superview) and the player should be set to nil, something like:

```
/* not sure if the pause/remove order would matter */
[playerLayer.player pause];
// uncomment if the player not needed anymore
// playerLayer.player = nil;
[playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Comment: Excuse me, sorry it's been a long time. But, where should I put the code below? in `viewDidDisappear:` or `viewWillDisappear:` ? I tried both, but none of them worked.... could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lilac did you ever figure out where to put this code?

Comment: @JayQ. I'm afraid that I didn't use this method to solve my issue. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer in Swift.

Like @Paresh Navadiya and @Yoga said in the comments below the answer. The playerLayer's player has to get set to nil. `playerLayer?.player = nil`

Add the code in viewWillDisappear:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        player?.pause() // 1. pause the player to stop it
        playerLayer?.player = nil // 2. set the playerLayer's player to nil
        playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer() // 3 remove the playerLayer from its superLayer
}
```